# Code works on Xcode 12.5 but not Xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This code compiles fine on Xcode 12.5.1 and 13

```
private func maskOtherLocalAccount(number: String?) -> String {
    guard let number = number, number.count > 5 else { return number ?? "-"}
}
```

But on Xcode 12.4, it gives this compile error:

```
Variable declared in 'guard' condition is not usable in its body
```

Though the fix is quite easy, I find it really strange that it works on Xcode 12.5.1 and not on 12.4.
Can someone point to an official changelog documenting this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reported by [SR-8669](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8669):

> If you attempt to use a guard statement to declare a variable that shadows an existing variable, a compiler error prevents you from accessing the existing variable in the body of the guard.

This is already marked resolved almost a whole year ago, which matches the release date of Xcode 12.5.